# Calls cut-off after 10 seconds (Samsung galaxy S3)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls

I have samsug galaxy s3 (SHV-E 210S), when I receive a call or when I make a call, it cuts off after 10 sec and I have to make a call again. In brief the call stop its self. What can you do to solve that issue. The phone don't allow me to control the calls (incoming and outgoing).

Comment: go to Service Center :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your call setting are pretty weird. Do following things :

1. Check your proximity sensors are working properly
2. Check your call setting might be it changed due to some third party app you installed.
3. Change the network provider( change 3g to 2g).
4. This probably is your second last option just reset your device ( backup needed)
5. The last I can say is contact Samsung dealers, that might help you.

Hope it helps.